# Property 'replaceReducer' does not exist on type 'Store<State>' After upgrading @ngrx/store

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

In my Angular app, I have a function which replaces replaces the current reducer used by the Store. However, after upgrade from @ngrx/store v2.2.2 to v6.1.0, "replaceReducer" function seems to have been removed from the Store interface.

I've gone through the NGRX migration guide (https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) hoping to find a possible solution or an alternative way to go around the issue but I can't find any reference to the removed "replaceReducer" function interface.

Here is my code:

```
export const accountingModuleReducer: ActionReducer<State> = createReducer(reducers);

export function accountingStoreFactory(appStore: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
  appStore.replaceReducer(accountingModuleReducer);
  return appStore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Reducer has been deprecated. Checkout this issue to see an alternative way to approach [this](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/165) problem. Also checkout the StoreModule.forFeature() docs [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/api.md#feature-module-state-composition), which might help you out.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it out